# Besseres Wort für "Lesebeitrag" in Careers (original: Reading)

Tags: translation, single-word-request

Nach [dieser Frage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284715/spelling-mistake-lesebeitr%C3%A4ge) stellte sich für mich die Frage, was *Lesebeiträge* eigentlich sind.

Beispielprofil: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ncraver

Im Englischen heißt der Punkt: "Reading" und beinhaltet gelesene Werke, Fachliteratur, eventuell auch bekannte Blogs oder Tutorials.

Meiner Meinung nach passt der Begriff *Lesebeitrag* nicht besonders gut, da *-beitrag* irgendwie fehl am Platz wirkt.

Hat jemand eine Idee, welches Wort besser passen würde?

*Fachliteratur* ist vermutlich zu speziell, da auch Dinge abgedeckt werden, die nicht direkt unter Literatur fallen bzw. normalerweise nicht als Literatur beschrieben werden. Es ist unklar, ob auch Dinge abgedeckt werden, die nicht zwingend zum "Fach" gehören müssen.

*Kenntnisse* ist dagegen vermutlich zu allgemein.

Comment: Leseempfehlungen?

Comment: Ich vermute dass bei "Leseempfehlungen" der Aspekt zu indirekt ist, dass man die "Literatur" wirklich gelesen hat, während man auf der anderen Seite nicht unbedingt alles was man kennt und verstanden hat auch empfehlen muss...

Comment: Ja, ist mir auch aufgefallen. Ist das einzige Wort, was mir eingefallen ist, das die Sache nicht zu sehr eingrenzt. Wie wäre's mit "Lesestoff"?

Comment: "Lesestoff" wirkt auf mich informell, obwohl es das vielleicht garnicht ist... "Lektüre" würde ich tendenziell eher auf Romane o.ä. beziehen und hört sich etwas geschwollen oder verspielt an. "Literatur" passt vielleicht doch noch am besten, da laut Wikipedia auch Blogs etc. hinzugezählt werden.

Comment: "Reading" scheint sich m. E. auf augenblicklichen Lesestoff zu beziehen. Ein Akademiker würde "Handapparat" sagen. Ein "Fachlektüre" kommt mir nicht geschwollen oder verspielt vor.

Comment: Nach nochmaligem Lesen der Careers Seite erscheint mit *Schreibbeiräge* ebenfalls holprig und ich würde es eher als *Veröffentlichungen* bezeichnen. Bei *Lesebeiträgen* scheint es sich um *Empfehlungen* zu handeln.

Answer (score 6):

*Lesebeitrag* im Sinne von *Sachen, die ich gelesen habe,* ist falsch.

Ein Lesebeitrag ist

- wenn jemand einen Beitrag zu etwas leistet, indem er/sie etwas vorliest (findet sich häufig)
- die "Lesegebühr" einer Bibliothek o. Ä.
- ein Artikel oder Ähnliches (z. B. eine Anekdote oder ein Bericht), den jemand veröffentlicht, eventuell durch Dritte, damit dieser gelesen wird (findet sich selten bei einigen Zeitungen, vielleicht aus Lese**r**beitrag entstanden?)

Dies sind zumindest die Kontexte, in denen mir das Wort *Lesebeitrag* bisher begegnet ist. Meiner Meinung nach ist es also definitiv falsch.

---

Eine passende Übersetzung ist schwierig, auch weil es im deutschen Sprachraum nicht üblich ist, so etwas anzugeben (wie schon von Micka erwähnt), und Lebensläufe in der Regel etwas formeller sind.

Ich würde das Wort *Fachlektüre* wählen. Lektüre impliziert, dass man das besagte Werk auch liest (oder auch gelesen hat).

Ein einfaches *Fachliteratur* ist in meinen Augen nicht ausreichend, da eine einfache Auflistung ohne Kontext befremdlich wirkt: "Wurde der Lebenslauf jetzt mit Hilfe der Fachliteratur erstellt? War der Schreiber Autor der angegebenen Werke oder irgendwie daran beteiligt?"

Ein *gelesene Fachliteratur* wirkt auch etwas gezwungen (irgendwie erwartet man ja auch, dass jemand Fachliteratur liest).

Das Ganze könnte man etwas auflockern, indem man z. B. von ***Meine Fachlektüre*** spricht.

Der Lebenslauf auf careers.stackoverflow.com ist nun mal etwas lockerer als der klassische deutsche Lebenslauf (Vorwort, Mein erster Computer etc.), daher kann man ruhig Possessivpronomen verwenden.

---

*Schreibbeiträge* finde ich auch etwas unpassend und es ist wie *Lesebeitrag* auch ein eher seltenes Wort.

(Das von bummi vorgeschlagene) *Veröffentlichungen* klingt auch sehr formell. Wenn jemand von einer Veröffentlichung spricht, dann erwartet man eher einen Artikel z. B. in einer angesehenen Fachzeitschrift statt ein Post auf seinem eigenen Blog.

Etwas unverfänglicher finde ich da ***Meine Artikel***, da sich dies sowohl auf (z. B. in der Zeitschrift) veröffentlichte Artikel als auch auf eigene Artikel im eigenen Blog (oder z. B. Google+ o. Ä.) beziehen kann.

---

TL;DR:

Ich würde ***Meine Fachlektüre***/***Meine Artikel*** statt ***Lesebeiträge***/***Schreibbeiträge*** empfehlen.

Comment: Kann es sein, dass Du in Beispiel 1 *Lesebeitrag* und *Lese**r**beitrag* verwechselt hast?

Comment: Aber was unterscheidet in Deinem Beispiel dann den *Lesebeitrag* vom *Beitrag,* das das Attribut *Lese-* rechtfertigt? Schließlich ist der Großteil des Inhalts einer Zeitung zum Lesen gedacht.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Was fragst du mich? Ich hab mir das ja nicht ausgedacht :-) Ich kenne es halt so, dass es in der Zeitung *Lesebeiträge* gibt, die nicht aus der Redaktion kommen. Zumindest bei meiner hiesigen Lokalzeitung; oder auch beim erstbesten Google-Ergebinis: [Lesebeitrag vom TC Weiß-Blau Fideliopark](http://www.abendzeitung-muenchen.de/inhalt.lesebeitrag-vom-tc-weiss-blau-fideliopark-mehr-als-sport-hier-lebt-die-gemeinschaft.1d88f852-ded2-48d7-9390-99ff01794daf.html)

Comment: In der Tat. Die ××××, die Münchner. Insbesondere, da der *Lesebeitrag* von einem *Lese**r**reporter* verfasst wurde.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Eventuell ist *Lesebetrag* im Sinne von *ein Artikel zum lesen* aus der falschen Schreibweise von *Leserbeitrag* entstanden (?) und meine Interpretation (Ein Lesebeitrag kommt ja nicht unbedingt von einem Leser) ist falsch. Ich habe mal weiter recherchiert, und die häufigste bedeutung von *Lesebetrag* scheint *jemand liest etwas vor zu sein*; *Lesebetrag* als *ein Artikel zum lesen* ist sehr selten.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, der _Lesebeitrag_ ist das textuelle Gegenstück zum _Hörbeitrag_. Wobei ich persönlich auch eher _Text-_ und _Tonbeiträge_ unterscheiden würde (bzw. auch _Audio-_ oder _Videobeiträge_).

Answer (score 6):

*Reading* und *Writing* im Kontext und Subtext der Seite richtig zu übersetzen finde ich extrem schwierig.

Die bisherigen Vorschläge Lesebeiträge, Schreibbeiträge, Fachlektüre, Veröffentlichungen etc. finde ich (durch die Bank) zu holperig, zu förmlich, unpassend.

Ich würde daher anregen, nah am Original, einfach wörtlich zu übersetzen: *Gelesenes*, *Geschriebenes* (oder *Gelesen* und *Geschrieben*).

Ich finde dadurch ist ausreichend deutlich, dass es sich um die eigene Lektüre, bzw. um die eigenen Veröffentlichungen handelt und belässt dabei Förmlichkeit und begriffliche (Un-)Präzision in einem angemessenen Rahmen.

Comment: Nicht schlecht, aber ich finde *Gelesenes* und *Geschriebenes* einfach zu unscharf bzw. zu unbestimmt (nicht dass das englische *Reading* und *Writing* in dieser Hinsicht besser wäre).

Comment: Wir haben den Vorschlag *Gelesen* und *Geschrieben* auf SO Careers übernommen, siehe http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247826/translation-error-lesebeitr%C3%A4ge/248018#248018

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde sogar noch einen Schritt weiter gehen, als [moooeeeep in seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20514/1224) vorschlägt, und es schlicht *Gelesen* und *Verfasst* nennen.

Und im Grunde hast du in deiner Frage selbst schon einen guten Vorschlag genannt: *Gelesene Werke*